# How do I change the height and width of StackView containing buttons from Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a stack view containing several buttons, It seems impossible for me to change the dimensions of the stack view.

The size of stack view is always fixed in Size Inspector: [image: Image1]

Even when I add constrains to the stack view, it just show warnings, without changing the size: [image]

Comment: Set Y position and height constraints also.

Comment: Yeah give it top constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Set height constraint in IB..........

[image]